# Stack two columns of fieldset boxes closely

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I've got a form with multiple fieldsets, of varying number of elements.
Is it possible to make the fieldset boxes fill the columns tightly, and not align with the one in the other column.

Example code (I want Block 3 straight below Block 1):

```css
fieldset {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 45%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid;
}

fieldset label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 24em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

fieldset legend {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<form method=post>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Block 1:</legend>
      ABC
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Block 2:</legend>
      ABC <br/> 
      DEF <br/> 
      GHI <br/> 
      JKL
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Block 3:</legend>
      ABC <br/>
      DEF <br/>
      GHI <br/>
      JKL
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I can't manually move these around as the order matters and the number of elements in each fieldset is dynamic (cgi python code).

Comment: what do you mean by straight??

Comment: Are you trying to set 3 column or in one  row ?

Comment: Have a good read on that: https://regisphilibert.com/blog/2017/12/pure-css-masonry-layout-with-flexbox-grid-columns-in-2018/

Comment: Straight -> Following without any gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide your fieldsets to 2 columns for that and use `vertical-align:top` to align the smallest column to the top

```css
.column1, .column2{
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
fieldset {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid;
}

fieldset label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 24em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

fieldset legend {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<form method=post>
    <div class="column1">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Block 1:</legend>
        ABC
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Block 3:</legend>
        ABC <br/>
        DEF <br/>
        GHI <br/>
        JKL
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Block 2:</legend>
        ABC <br/> 
        DEF <br/> 
        GHI <br/> 
        JKL
      </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This does what I want, but required me to segment them into the columns. This is the solution I'm using for now.

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at [multi-column-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts) / [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)

```css
form {
column-count:2;
column-fill:balance;
padding-top:1em;
}
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid;
}

fieldset label {
  display: block;
  width: 24em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

fieldset legend {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<form method=post>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Block 1:</legend>
      ABC
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Block 2:</legend>
      ABC <br/> 
      DEF <br/> 
      GHI <br/> 
      JKL
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Block 3:</legend>
      ABC <br/>
      DEF <br/>
      GHI <br/>
      JKL
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

`display:grid` could help but you will have to set manually rows and columns where to stand and how much row or columns to span.

`display:flex` will require a set height to wrap content to next column.

`column` seems the closer to your needs

Comment: The solution looks like what I want, but the ordering is wrong.
It looks like column is the way to go.